# How to set value in component from ajax request to parameters during creation in Vue?

Tags: ajax, vuejs2, axios

I am learning Vue and trying to set one value in component during its creation from one Ajax request.

Here is the structure of `src` folder:

```
src
    assets
    components
        Management.vue
    router
        index.js
    vuex
        modules
            caseSuiteList.js
        index.js
        actions.js
        getters.js
    App.vue
    main.js
```

Management.vue:

```
<template>
</template>
<script>
  import {mapState} from 'vuex'
  import store from 'vuex'
    export default {
      name: "Management",
      computed: mapState({
        suite_list: state => state.caseSuiteList.suite_list
      }),
      created(){
        store.dispatch('refresh')
      }
    }
</script>
```

caseSuiteList.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const state = {
  suite_list : {}
}

const mutations = {
  refreshSuiteList(state, payload) {
    state.suite_list = payload
  }
}

const actions = {
  refresh (context) {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8601/haha').then(function(res){
      console.log(res.data);
      context.commit('refreshSuiteList', res.data);
    }
    });
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

How to dispatch `action` of `caseSuiteList.js` in `created()` of `Management.vue` to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dispatching in the created hook of your component.

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('refresh');
  }
```

More information about Vuex: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html

Answer (score 1):

Within the vue instance (or any component within) you access the store with `this.$store`.